# Opto-coupler output photo-transistor as normal BJT

Tags: switches, bjt, opto-isolator, isolation

I am currently using a 4N49 opto for command isolation (no speed requirements, just isolation for a slow 64ms signal). There is different section of the design which also needs a NPN transistor switch. Would there be any issues, if I use the output phototransistor as a normal BJT switch. (ignore the ground connections and part values, couldnt find the 4N49 in circuit lab). SPICE simulations work fine, will try on the breadboard

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foLPAg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have verified this in spice with the schematic below.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to use a LED LTL-307EE  to controle a 2N3904 transistor (which is not a phototransistor) or do mean something else?

Comment: It depends how you connect it. The example connections you provided would override the base completely, so most likely the LED would not be able to turn the transistor on.

Comment: @PaulGhobril, the shown circuit is just indicative (am new to drawing in circuit lab), I am attaching the SPICE file soon enough.

Comment: Parameter like hfe undefined, so it is not for mass production.

Comment: I have access to Hfe tested opto-couplers. And as the intention is to use the output stage as a switch, the Hfe spread should'nt be much of a concern as long as I hold Ic<= Ib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phototransistors are designed with a huge base in order to catch as much light as possible. This makes them very slow.

However, they still work like normal BJTs. The photocurrent from the base-collector photodiode is rather small and needs amplification, so you will be able to switch it on by providing a reasonable base current.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would want to do this. But if you needed to replace a plain NPN BJT in a circuit, and you only had a optocoupler in your parts bin, this would be a basic equivalent. This would work for a basic switch, but would not necessarily work for all applications.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIGmbc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I am fine with the idea of using a single opto as a replacement for a BJT. The query I have is a bit different. I need command Isolation for V1 (Pulse input to the opto LED) and  current amplification for V2 (Pulse input for the phototransistor base). Put simply, I need to OR two signals, of which one is to be isolated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the circuit you provided will work. I do not know why this would be helpful, because you could just use a regular BJT or use the LED of the opto coupler to switch the BJT.